# How can i manage to loop the group_concat value into datatable and checkboxes

Tags: laravel, datatable

i am storing id_supplier in product table. I able to display it in table by just one row for each item code with it's supplier id. I also need the name of supplier as well, but i face problem on separating id and name.

```
//query
select code, group_concat(s.supplier_id,s.supplier_name) AS supplier_id_name
from catalog c
left join product p on p.product_id= c.product_id
left join supplier s on s.supplier_id = p.product_id
group by code;


    //query will show following output

    id supplier - 1,  name - abc
    id supplier - 2, name - def

    Code        | Supplier
    A001        | 1abc,2def  // id and name of supplier
```

What i am expected

```
Code        | Supplier
A001        | checkboxes value = 1 and then display supplier name beside....... and continue in the same row if  more supplier
```

There will be a checkbox for every supplier display for the code and checkbox will contain the supplier id for storing purpose.

How can i do this?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you might want to look into handling this in your presentation layer, rather than purely in MySQL.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Incidentally, to a rough approximation, there is no problem in sql for which group_concat need form any part of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.

**Solution 1:** Compose HTML code just by MySQL query itself, by using following sql:

```
// Query

SELECT CODE, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<input type="checkbox" value="', s.supplier_id, '"> ', s.supplier_name) SEPARATOR ',') AS supplier_id_names
    FROM catalog c
    LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id= c.product_id
    LEFT JOIN supplier s ON s.supplier_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY CODE;
```

**Solution 2:** First grab supplier id and name separated by specific char, and then in backend code, filter each id and name by splitting it, to produce the full HTML code: (Following is PHP code)

```
$query= "SELECT CODE, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(s.supplier_id, ':', s.supplier_name) SEPARATOR '|||') AS supplier_id_names
    FROM catalog c
    LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_id= c.product_id
    LEFT JOIN supplier s ON s.supplier_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY CODE";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // get html for each row
    $checkboxHtml = '';
    $idSups = explode('|||', $row['supplier_id_names']);
    foreach($idSups AS $s) {
        list($i,$s) = explode(':', $s);
        $checkboxHtml .= '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $i . '"> ' . $s;
    }
    // do something else...
}
```